# Unable to print logs in Smart contract written in nodejs and deployed on hyperledger-fabric

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts

Hi I am running a smart contract written in nodejs and deployed on hyperledger-fabric 1.2. The smart contract or the code chain runs perfectly however does not print any logs. I have printed the logs using console.log() statement.

Have already tried multiple wrokarounds but none seem to work.
1) Redirected console.log() output to a file and overridden the console.log function a per the solution suggested here.

```
const util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var log_file = fs.createWriteStream('ankurkhera.log', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function(d) { //
  log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};
```

2) Tried using the shim.newLogger function and printed the logs but did not work.

```
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
var testLog = shim.newLogger('ankurkhera');
testLog.info('============= START : createSpend ===========')
```

3) Tried looking at logs using but nothing

```
docker logs -f <container id>
```

This is code for my smart contract below

```
'use strict';
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
const util = require('util');

var testLog = shim.newLogger('ankurkhera');
var fs = require('fs');
var log_file = fs.createWriteStream('ankurkhera.log', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function(d) { //
  log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};

async createSpend(stub, args) {
    console.log('how are you'); //DOES NOT GET SAVED TO FILE
    testLog.info('============= START : createSpend ===========');// NO Logs
    testLog.info('============= END : createSpend ===========');
  }
```

I expect to view the logs for me to debug my smart contract written in nodejs and deployed on hyperledger fabric 1.2.

Comment: Can you please share the core.yaml file as well?

Comment: is this the file you are talking https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain/blob/master/ngo-fabric/docker-compose-cli.yaml

Answer (score 4):

You should check the logs of your chaincode in chaincode container because the logs of smart contract are written inside its container. You can look up for the container on which chaincode is using using

```
docker ps -a
```

and here you can easily see the container that's up for your chaincode then you can follow the logs of your chaincode:

```
docker logs --follow [chaincode-container-id]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could view the logs of smart contract - 
First check the running docker container using -

```
docker ps -a
```

Now you could see the list of various running/existed containers here, you need to logs the instantiate chaincode container. Use the command mentioned below -

```
docker logs --follow **<container id of chaincode listed above>**
```

***Your chaincode container should be up & Running to check the logs**

Comment: Could you share the screen shot of docker ps. And let us know, what is name of your chaincode.

Comment: i am running the hyper-ledger fabric on aws managed blockchain, here is the screenshot.

Comment: Not able to see the ss.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger fabric uses environment variables to set various parameters for peers and orderers,one of the parameter set for the peers is **chaincode logging**

The environment variables for peers can be set in two ways

1. By creating a core.yaml file and mounting it to the peer / by adding these variables in the environment section of the docker-compose file for the desired peers.
2. By passing the environment variables where the peer is installed using export command.

In your case It seems like you are trying to use shim logger on the above aws template
 you could either add the bellow env variable to the individual peer conatiners/VPC's by using

```
export CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO    
export CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=INFO
```

or add it to enviroments section to your docker compose file

```
 - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
 - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=INFO
```

Hope this helps.